# Bootstrap 4 Tab not activated unless clicked

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 tabs for the menu control in my angular project.
Menu.Component.html

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" >Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"  [routerLink]="['/search']" >Search</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"  [routerLink]="['/finance']" >Finance</a>
    </li>  
    </ul>
```

app.routing.ts

```
    const MAINMENU_ROUTES: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
        { path:'finance', component: FinanceComponent}
    ];
    export const CONST_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(MAINMENU_ROUTES);
```

The landing page for the application is Dashboard. When i run the application, Dashboard component is loaded, but the tab is not activated.
similiarly, if i type the any other url directly , components are loaded correctly, but no tabs are not activated/selected.

Please help.
Note: If i click on the tab icon, everything works fine.

Refer below images:

[image]

This should be like

[image]

And

[image]

should be like

[image]

Comment: Can you create a replica of your code on stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below HTML code it should work same thing i did in my code its working:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" >Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a  [routerLink]="['/search']" >Search</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a [routerLink]="['/finance']" >Finance</a>
    </li>  
    </ul>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this ?